# Wordpress Woocommerce product-category info on one line

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

As the title says. 
I want to list info about different courses with info where each class have all the info, including the "Add to Cart" button, on one line. 
I've managed to change the SKU and Categories to time and place. I've found the CSS that styles (.berocket_lgv_additional_data) but can't get it to show all info on one line.

I would think if I get the PHP that shows product name and product description mated in meta.php with old SKU and Categories it would show on one line?

Also, that button on the left side is killing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if someone wants to know.
I used the plugin Grid/List View for WooCommerce.
Then added a div in the php script additional_product_data.php 
The div i called wrapper and included all the divs in that script.

Then i gave the div id="wrapper" display=inline block in my templates style.css
Also all the other "display" in the css doc of the plugin was given; inline block. Then i got all the info on one line.